# 230v Electric Cooker

Tags: wiring, kitchens, stove

is the wiring correct this way ?
in the plug, should the brown cable be wired in the R1(L1) or T3(L3)? [image: 23v]
[image: coocker][image: Plug]

Comment: What's your supply at the outlet? 1 phase 2 phase or 3 phase, the plug looks capable of three phase.

Comment: Yeah its a three phase

Comment: Wow, that's not even close.  Might want to hire a pro before you hurt somebody...  400V is serious stuff ([this is what 480V looks like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hpE5LYj-CY), yours is only 17% less).

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the socket for this appliance is a three-phase one to physically match the plug you show.  (Otherwise, obviously, you could not plug it in).

If that socket is actually wired with two or three phases of power available, then your appliance plug is not wired correctly.   You could remove the jumper shown in the first picture and make use of additional phases via the unused grey and/or white wires in the power cord.

On the other hand, if you only have one phase of power available at this location, or perhaps in your home entirely, and a 5-pin socket was installed just to suit appliances like this one that come with the three phases jumpered as shown, then your plug is wired correctly.

Additionally, referring to the diagram in the first picture, if you are powering the appliance via one phase, as currently wired, you should make sure that power cord (which in fact has 5 conductors) contains 4mm^2 wires.  I cannot tell from the picture how fat the wires are.  If they are smaller than 4mm^2 AND you only have one phase of power available at the socket, you should entirely replace the power cord.

Comment: Its a 3 phase socket, check out the link

Comment: https://www.dmlights.be/abb__vynckier__32a_grijs~19QIT?gclid=Cj0KCQiA1pyCBhCtARIsAHaY_5eHknYVuQCWNp-G0ABn7jM2Rk8uFwueNNJRCRDBItkkzFJ_wLjDApAaAlkyEALw_wcB

Comment: @RayanMh thanks, I have expanded and clarified my answer to better explain what I meant by "3 phase socket".   I think we can assume the socket is PHYSICALLY what you've shown, otherwise hopefully OP would be asking a much more obvious question!  My original answer meant "actually wired with more than one phase available and live" but it was unclear.